# Wikipedia API get links to all images of preferred redirected articles in one API call?

Tags: wikipedia-api

I want to get the links to all the images for the default redirect pages for, say, "Hypertensive Disease" and "pulmonary edema." Right now, I am doing this through three api calls for each term. E.g,

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=hypertensive_disease&redirects&prop=links&format=json&indexpageids
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&pageids=RESULT_FROM_1&prop=images&format=json
3. ...api.php?action=query&titles=RESULTS_FROM_2&prop=imageinfo&&iiprop=url&iiurlwidth=220&format=json

Where 1 gets the IDs for the redirects, 2 gets the image names, and 3 gets the image URLs.

Is there a way to be nicer to wikipedia and do this with one API call?

Comment: What does "preferred redirected articles" or "default redirect pages" mean? Your query just gets all the links from the given article.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was just grabbing the first link from that array of all links.

Comment: That just gives you the link that's first alphabetically. I don't understand how could that be useful.

Comment: Yes, I think my implementation is sloppy in that regard. I suppose what I wanted was something along the lines of when I search wikipedia for "hypertensive diseases," I automatically get redirected to an article titled "Hypertension." I wanted to tap into whatever logic wikipedia is using to redirect me to a single page.

Comment: You already do that by setting `redirects`. But then you also add `prop=links`, to get articles like "ABIM Foundation". That's the part that I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can make use of a generator, so the single API call to get all images from the defaulted redirected page for "hypertensive disease" ("Hypertension") would look like this:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=hypertensive_disease&redirects&generator=images&prop=imageinfo&&iiprop=url&format=json&indexpageids
```

Comment: Thanks for remembering to come back and answer this :)